# Help with limit without using Taylor series

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I would like help solving the following limit:

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^6 - \arctan(x^6)}{(x - \sin(x))^6}$,

but I do not want to use Taylor series. It would be nice to have an answer that does not use L'Hôpital as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to use Taylor series!  You don't want to use L'Hopital's rule!

You are at Mathematica StackExchange, so maybe you want to use Mathematica?!

```
Limit[(x^6-ArcTan[x^6])/(x-Sin[x])^6,x->0]
```

(* 15552 *)